# Python y Mysql no se atrapa la excepción

Tags: mysql, python

No consigo atrapar este error: `Warning: (1050, "Table 't12345' already exists")`
A pesar que tengo el código de esta forma:

```
try:
    cursor.execute('''
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS T12345 (
        RNC VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
        CELL VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
        C67194793 INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
        C67194794 INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
        C67194795 INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
        C67194796 INT(11) DEFAULT NULL
        ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;''')

except:
    print("Tabla T12345 ya esta creada")
```

Gracias adelantadas

Comment: En este caso tu query dice CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS.. o sea que si existe no la va a crear y no hay error.

Comment: Ahí está el asunto, amigo @gbianchi. Que si me lanza el error. No lo comprendo. 
`Warning: (1050, "Table 't12345' already exists")`

Comment: Y vos estas seguro que la excepcion que lanza es porque la tabla esta creada y no por otra? tu except es general, o sea que cualquier error va a entrar por ahi y va a tirar el mensaje que vos le decis que tire. No se tanto python como para ayudarte con el codigo, pero deberias verificar que excepcion realmente estas recibiendo

Comment: podrias usar algo asi:...except (MySQLdb.Error, MySQLdb.Warning) as e:....print(e)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los `warnings` son exactamente eso, advertencias, no son errores que puedas capturar, entiendo que sean molestos por que se suelen ver en la salida estándar, pero en tu caso no es ninguna advertencia que valga la pena capturar ya que `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` es una situación totalmente manejada y controlada por la base de datos.

Lo que si puedes hacer con los `warnings` es configurar el comportamiento:

Por ejemplo, para transformarlos en excepciones y capturarlos luego como tales

```
import warnings, MySQLdb
warnings.filterwarnings('error', category=MySQLdb.Warning)
```

o bien

```
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', category=MySQLdb.Warning)
```

fuente: [trapping a MySql warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2102251/trapping-a-mysql-warning)